# Forcing decimal places in Google Apps Script when writing to a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, number-formatting

I have a script that processes a google spreadsheet. 
if I have a variable "myVariable" which has a value of 2.10 and use the function
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(,).setValue(myVariable) it is stored as 2.1 instead of 2.10.
When I call the value again, the last decimal places get truncated if they are zero. Since these are fiscal numbers I need to keep the two decimal places.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

You can just format the cell in the sheet from **Format>Number>Automatic** to **Format>Number>Number**.

But if you want to achieve it using App script itself then just add this line :

```
var myVariable = 2.10;
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(,).setValue(myVariable);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(,).setNumberFormat("0.00"); // Add this line to your code
```